# Intuitive explanation on dependence of Hamiltonian simulation on norm?

Tags: complexity-theory, hamiltonian-simulation, hamiltonian

Suppose I have two Hamiltonians, $H_1$ and $H_2$, that I want to simulate for time $T$. If $\|\|H_1\|\|>\|\|H_2\|\|$, why is it more costly to simulate $H_1$ compared to $H_2$? Is there an intuitive reasoning behind this?